# LibreOffice replace macro - replace only once and replace by format

Tags: replace, macros, libreoffice

In LibreOffice Writer, I would like to write a macro that finds a certain string (e.g. "abc") and replaces it with another string ("def"), but, only if the original string is in boldface. Moreover, I want to do this only for the first match.

This is easy to do using LibreOffice search-and-replace dialog,  but, I cannot find a way to do it in a macro:

- First, in [this API reference](http://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/servicecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1util_1_1ReplaceDescriptor.html) I do not see a setting related to finding only boldface strings. The nearest match is "SearchStyles", but this refers to styles of entire paragraphs rather than search words.
- Second,  I do not see a command for replacing only the first occurence; I see only "replaceAll".

Is there a way to replace only boldface words, and only the first match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) has a number of good examples related to searching.  The following was adapted from listing 7.41 and listing 7.45.

```vb
Sub FindBoldString
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim oSearch As Object
    Dim oFound As Object
    Dim srchAttributes(0) As New com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    oSearch = oDoc.createSearchDescriptor()
    oSearch.SearchString = "abc"
    oSearch.SearchRegularExpression=False
    oSearch.searchStyles = True
    oSearch.searchAll = False
    srchAttributes(0).Name = "CharWeight"
    srchAttributes(0).Value = com.sun.star.awt.FontWeight.BOLD
    oSearch.SetSearchAttributes(srchAttributes)
    oFound = oDoc.findFirst(oSearch)
    If Not IsNull(oFound) Then
        oFound.SetString("def")
        oFound.CharWeight = com.sun.star.awt.FontWeight.BOLD
    End If
End Sub
```